# Does ejabberd 16.12.34 supports mod_push? Any alternative for sending push notifications through ejabberd?

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd

I am following these instructions:

git clone https://github.com/royneary/mod_push.git

## copy the source code folder to the module sources folder of your ejabberd

## installation (may be different on your machine)

sudo cp -R mod_push /var/spool/jabber/.ejabberd-modules/sources/

## if done right ejabberdctl will list mod_push as available module

ejabberdctl modules_available

## automatically compile and install mod_push

ejabberdctl module_install mod_push

But i got these errors: (part of errors)

```
/Users/.ejabberd-modules/sources/mod_push/ebin/mod_push_gcm.bea#: error writing file: no such file or directory
/Users/.ejabberd-modules/sources/mod_push/ebin/mod_push_mozilla.bea#: error writing file: no such file or directory
/Users/.ejabberd-modules/sources/mod_push/src/mod_push_mozilla.erl:74: Warning: variable 'DisableArgs' is unused
/Users/.ejabberd-modules/sources/mod_push/ebin/mod_push_ubuntu.bea#: error writing file: no such file or directory
/Users/.ejabberd-modules/sources/mod_push/src/mod_push_ubuntu.erl:74: Warning: variable 'DisableArgs' is unused
/Users/.ejabberd-modules/sources/mod_push/src/mod_push_ubuntu.erl:139: Warning: erlang:now/0: Deprecated BIF. See the "Time and Time Correction in Erlang" chapter of the ERTS User's Guide for more information.
/Users/.ejabberd-modules/sources/mod_push/ebin/mod_push_wns.bea#: error writing file: no such file or directory
/Users/.ejabberd-modules/sources/mod_push/src/mod_push_wns.erl:84: Warning: variable 'DisableArgs' is unused
/Users/.ejabberd-modules/sources/mod_push/src/mod_push_wns.erl:160: Warning: variable 'ReplyHead' is unused
/Users/.ejabberd-modules/sources/mod_push/ebin/node_push.bea#: error writing file: no such file or directory
Error: {compilation_failed,"/Users/.ejabberd-modules/sources/mod_push/src/mochijson2.erl"}
```

Does anyone have dealt with this?

Please specify alternatives for sending push notifications through ejabberd server.

Answer (score 0):

`mod_push` doesn't work with ejabberd 16.12+ versions.
Please see the related github issue: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/1379

Comment: Can you please specify alternatives to implement push notification with ejabberd?

Comment: I'm aware of commercial verion of ejabberd only which supports push notifications.